# Can be fast refreshable a partitioned materialized view with a json_table on it?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a materialized view like this:

```
create materialized view MVW_AMOV 
    PARTITION BY RANGE (LOAD_DATE) INTERVAL ( numtodsinterval(1,'DAY'))
    (  
      PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2018-12-26 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
        LOGGING
        NOCOMPRESS
    )
    PARALLEL 16
    BUILD DEFERRED
    USING INDEX
    REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
    USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS 
    DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
    as 
        select /*+ parallel(8) pq_distribute(tab1 hash hash)*/ 
           c.msisdn, c.doc, c.load_date, j.documentNumber, j.documentType, 
           j.birthDate, j.nationality, j.segment, j.lineStatus, j.startServiceData, j.endServiceData,
           j.tariff
        from rep_trs_carga c, 
            json_table(aditional_data, '$.operatorMobile'
              columns (
                nested path '$[*]' 
                columns 
                    ( documentNumber varchar2(100) path '$.documentNumber',
                    documentType varchar2(100) path '$.documentType',
                    birthDate number path '$.birthDate',                
                    nationality varchar2(100) path '$.segment',
                    segment varchar2(100) path '$.segment',
                    lineStatus varchar2(100) path '$.lineStatus',
                    startServiceData number path '$.startServiceData',                
                    endServiceData number path '$.endServiceData',               
                    tariff varchar2(100) path '$.tariff'               
                    )
                )  
              )j;
```

I tried to make it fast refreshable, but I obtain an ORA-12015 error.

You know where is the problem? Is the json_table function?

Thanks in advance. Regards.